# excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I open, edit, read excel columns in vb.net? Like, for example, I want to know the values of column B up to the cell that it contains values. Thank you.

Comment: @sef The Excel file format comes in like a billion flavors:  .xls (binary), .xlsx (a weird XML "open" format), .csv (comma separated value), etc.  Are you wanting to read all formats, or just 1?  Does the user need to have Excel installed on the computer already (COM components) or do you want the reading excel files to be stand alone?  Is it acceptable to only support common formats (like CSV) or does it have to be specifically Excel format?

Comment: Can someone please look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312680/pivottable-pivotfields-does-not-detect-any-fields-in-case-of-external-datasource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ADO.Net.

Here's [a link](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=54).

More examples:

[Read excel 1st sheet into VB.NET](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/21d3f77c-1d3d-44e0-9bd5-eca45a0affa6)

[Reading Cells in Excel Using VB.NET](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=468326)

[How to open Excel 2007 in vb.net](http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm)