# Pivottable.pivotfields does not detect any fields in case of external datasource

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vb.net

I am using a pivot which connects to an external datasource. When i display field list, it shows the datasource name "Source" at the top. I am trying to loop through the fields using PivotTable.PivotFields. Its not entering the loop at all.
Desired behaivior: It should enter the loop and the field names should be appended to the string.

```
For Each pvtField As PivotField In pvttable.PivotFields
mRetVal = mRetVal & pvtField.Name & "-" & pvtField.SourceName & "-" & pvtField.SourceCaption & ","
Next
```

Comment: How did you connect to the external datasource? As long as you don't also see some field names in your field list (below the datasource name), you can't address them as `PivotField`.

Comment: Thanks Asger. I can see field names in the listing. All the field names seem to be child of the Source (as I mentioned above). I tried looping through the names but it never entered the loop.

Comment: One more thing I should mention here. I tried creating another pivot which is connected to a table in the same document. The loop works perfectly fine in this case.

Comment: I am beginning to think no one is interested in this topic. The issue is very much live and bugging me like anything. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write it in VBA, here's some help.
In VBA you generally have to separate variable declarations like this:

```
Dim pvtField As PivotField
For Each pvtField In pvttable.PivotFields
    mRetVal = mRetVal & pvtField.Name & "-" & pvtField.SourceName & "-" & pvtField.SourceCaption & ","
Next pvtField
```

If your pivot table is based on an external source (OLAP), then you can also loop through the `CubeFields` which have some different properties:

```
Dim pvtCubeField as CubeField
For Each pvtCubeField In pvttable.CubeFields
    mRetVal = mRetVal & pvtCubeField.Name & "-" & pvtCubeField.Value & "-" & pvtCubeField.Caption & ","
Next pvtCubeField
```

As `CubeFields` from the OLAP source and `PivotFields` from the pivot table are linked, you may select the `PivotFields` by this again:

```
Dim pvtCubeField as CubeField, pvtField As PivotField
For Each pvtCubeField In pvttable.CubeFields
    For Each pvtField In pvtCubeField.PivotFields
        mRetVal = mRetVal & pvtField.Name & "-" & pvtField.SourceName & "-" & pvtField.SourceCaption & ","
    Next pvtField
Next pvtCubeField
```

Comment: Will try the cubefield approach and let you know. Thanks Asger.

Comment: You may get your desired info via `CubeField.PivotField`, so I added that also.

Comment: If my answer helps, please do me a favor and mark the checkbox beneath it (reason is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: could you please have a look at this as well...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940059/slicer-connections-does-not-show-pivottable-post-change-datasource